# Changing / writing to element using casperjs and capture screenshot after the change

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

Is it possible to change / add style to an element / DOM using casperjs ? 
I would like to highlight the element before I capture a screenshot

I've tried doing the following:

1.Change the element - just adding border - this part works.

```
$(":contains('something')").filter(function() {
                        return (
                            $(this).clone() //clone the element
                                .children() //select all the children
                                .remove() //remove all the children
                                .end() //again go back to selected element
                                .filter(":contains('something')").length > 0)
                    }).css('border', 'solid 1px black');
```

2.Then capture a screenshot after the change.

```
                this.capture('test.png', undefined, {
                    format: 'jpg',
                    quality: 75
                });
```

Screenshot is taken but without the changes I've made on the element.

Comment: How do you have the two code blocks wrapped? Are they both inside `casper.start()`?

Comment: It's in casper.then function - both of the blocks

Comment: Just eliminating the obvious: 1) Do you get the same result if you put them in separate `then()` calls? 2) Do you get the same result if you perform a simpler (and less async-y) jQuery DOM operation? So for example do something like `$('#something').css('background-color', 'red')`.

Comment: Yes for both of the questions , it seems like the casperjs ignores the changes that are made using the jQuery , is there any other way to change / manipulate an element using casperjs functions ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it that way :

First here a function which returns the css property of an element

```
//return the css property of an element called by its selector
//getElementBounds() not sufficient
casper.css = function(selector,propertyName){
     "use strict";
    var css = this.evaluate(function(sel,prop) {
            return $(sel).css(prop);
        },selector,propertyName);
    return css;
    };
```

And after i would use waitFor() :

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function(){
    //here your jQuery code 
})
.waitFor(function check(){
    //wait this code to be true, so when one of your element has been modified
    return (casper.css("your selector","border")==="solid 1px black");
//then execute this function asking for the capture
},function then(){
     this.capture('test.png');
    }
//if waitFor never becomes true, that means your jQuery code or my function doesn't work
},function timeout(){
    casper.test.fail("Fail to modify elements");
});
```

I just give you my idea, the code doesn't work, or it might be if you specify the selector of one element which will be modified.